# azure application settings - how to add nested item

Tags: azure, azureportal

i have a appservice on azure that is running a .net core api.

in my appsettings.json file i have a section something similar to :

```
"Serilog": {    
"LevelSwitches": { "$controlSwitch": "Information" },
"MinimumLevel": {
  "ControlledBy": "$controlSwitch",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "LOGS\\log.json",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
    }
  },      
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": {
      "serverUrl": "https://MyLoggingServer",
      "apiKey": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
      "controlLevelSwitch": "$controlSwitch"          
    }
  }
]}
```

In azure appsetting section on the azure portal i'm not sure how i would go about setting the apiKey, in other more simple settings i have another section in appsettings.json

```
 "CustomSettings": {    
    "MySpecificSetting": "ABCDEFG",    
  }
```

Then in azure portal i have been able to set the setting by doing the following

```
CustomSettings:MySpecificSetting
```

but i'm not sure how this syntax would allow me to access the specific item in the writeTo array

Thanks for any help

Comment: What was the actual syntax for getting the api key?

Comment: using the example above the answer was to use following  Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:apiKey   where the number 1 is the array number.

Comment: Azure apparently isn't allowing ":" characters in settings any more.

Comment: @JimmyShoe Thanks! I hate this but Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:connectionString worked in my situation. In Azure config, is it possible to do something like Serilog:WriteTo:[Name='MSSqlServer']:Args:connectionString rather than using an array index?

Comment: @TimothyLeeRussell so the index start from 1?

Comment: @Yiping It is json, so it is 0-based.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you use : to nest:keys:down

cross platform you use __ to nest__keys__down (since : are bad for envars in *nix)

the key thing is it's not azure doing anything special... azure just sets env vars for the app from there.  it's .net core config that's actually looking at the env vars and doing special things see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#hierarchical-configuration-data & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#non-prefixed-environment-variables

Comment: This worked for me, _but_, I had to manually restart the app after saving, even though the save-dialog says "this will restart the app". For anyone here struggling with the same issue.

Comment: ':' is not allowed in azure app settings?

Comment: @Enrico they don't work in *nix

Answer (score 20):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#app-settings) article, you would have to use syntax something like "CustomSettings__MySpecificSetting".

Hope this helps!! Cheers!! :)

Comment: Ah! It seems like it's a Linux-specific thing: `In a default Linux container or a custom Linux container, any nested JSON key structure in the app setting name like ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey needs to be configured in App Service as ApplicationInsights__InstrumentationKey for the key name. In other words, any : should be replaced by __ (double underscore).`

Comment: To be precise, both `:` (single colon) and `__` (double underscore) will work in Windows environments, only `__` will work in Linux. So for safety's sake, use `__`.

Comment: Double underscore and neither : works for me,