# Nested object from local.settings.json in Azure function v3 settings

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure function v3 in .NET core 3.1
Function works fine locally.
Here is the local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "Foo": {
    "Bar": {
      "test1": true,
      "test2": false
    }
  }
}
```

I need to write a configuration for a nested object like Foo:Bar:test1 in Azure function configuration.

How to express this nested object there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [azure application settings - how to add nested item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497468/azure-application-settings-how-to-add-nested-item) (Answer is for web apps, but functions should work the same)

Comment: Azure functions and web apps behave differently. Look at this for more insight (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63124002/1138731)

Comment: but how are you reading the configuration in the function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct syntax for configuration options for Azure functions to express nested objects is to use double underscore: "CustomSettings__MySpecificSetting".

For a nested object in local.settings.json file:

```
"Foo": {
   "Bar": {
     "test1": true
    }
}
```

The Azure configuration looks like:

```
Foo__Bar__test1
```