# Azure function nested configuration

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In my local.settings I have nested settings like this

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "Email:Email": "test",
    "Email:Password": "*******",
  },
}
```

I am reading the values like this

```
config.GetValue<string>("Email:Email")
```

But when I am adding azure settings in azure function app (after deploying) I cannot add **:** into the name. Any suggestions for it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow,

*When we are creating azure function in local and deploy to azure our `localsettings.json` file not upload .We need to update them manually by adding it on portal.*

***In `localsettings.json` file you have used `:` which is accepted by local environment. But When deploying we need to use `__` instead.***

*Followed by this* [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings):-

> ***The app setting name like `ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey`***
> ***needs to be configured in App Service as***
> ***`ApplicationInsights__InstrumentationKey` for the key name. In other***
> ***words, any `:` should be replaced by `__` (double underscore).***

*Likewise you can set something like below e.g;*

```
"Email__Email": "test",
    "Email__Password": "*******",
```

*For more information please refer this* **SO THREAD**| [***azure application settings - how to add nested item***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55586184) & [***Nested object from local.settings.json in Azure function v3 settings***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63232949) .